# hg refuses to merge

Tags: mercurial

This is my problem:

```
(oneclickcosvirt)[marcintustin@web316 oneclickcos]$ hg merge
abort: outstanding uncommitted changes
(use 'hg status' to list changes)
(oneclickcosvirt)[marcintustin@web316 oneclickcos]$ hg ci -umarcintustin
nothing changed (4 missing files, see 'hg status')
```

Hg won't merge because of outstanding changes, but there are no outstanding changes. What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @gavinb's answer, it is also possible to pass the `--force` option:

```
hg merge --force
```

That will also perform the usual merge operation.

Answer (score 4):

The error message says there are 4 missing files.  So most likely the tree is considered in an inconsistent state such that it cannot merge as is.  If you do an `hg status` as it suggests, you will presumably see a series of files marked thus:

```
! foo.txt
! baz.txt
! bar.txt
! quux.txt
```

The state of these files needs to be resolved before the merge, either by removing them (`hg rm -A` if you really don't want them any more) or restoring them to the last commit (`hg revert`).

Once they are resolved, you should be able to merge as normal.